# Lodash Template Syntax

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am using Lodash template syntax in one of the projects.

The template syntax is used to generate a URL for a preview.

This is the syntax itself:

```
"url": ":baseUrl<%= pageSlug %>/<% _.forEach(locations, function(location) { %><%= location.locationName %><% }); %>/<%= studyMode %>",
```

This syntax will generate this URL:

https://preview-test.gtsb.io/landing-page/location-example/part-time

But in case there is no **locations** it will generate this:

https://preview-test.gtsb.io/landing-page//part-time

So there is two forward slashes that should be removed in case there is no **locations**

Is there a way to modify this syntax so in case there are no **locations**

it generates a correct URL like this:

https://preview-test.gtsb.io/landing-page/part-time

I've tried looking up in the documentation of Lodash but I wasn't able to find something like this.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `join` on the locations, instead of manually doing it via iteration.

Comment: Would you be kind and maybe provide an example of how it could be done? Thanks!

Comment: `["a", "b", "c"].join("/")` --> `"a/b/c"`; `["a", "b"].join("/")` --> `"a/b"`; `["a"].join("/")` --> `"a"`; `[].join("/")` --> `""`

Comment: Thanks, that part is understandable but how to write that within the template syntax?

Comment: Sorry - got a bit overwhelmed by the syntax. I found the solution ---> 
```baseUrl<%= pageSlug %><% _.forEach(locations, function(location) { %>/<%= location.locationName %><% }); %>/<%= pageSlug %>```

Thanks anyway